# Determinant of a Frenet curve

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature, frenet-frame

I have this problem:

> Let $c$ be a Frenet curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that
> $
> \operatorname{Det}\left(c^{\prime}, c^{\prime \prime}, \ldots, c^{(n)}\right)=\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\kappa_i\right)^{n-i}
> $

I've been struggling trying to understand how to solve it. This problem is from Kuhnel's Differential Geometry book.

I have these two properties that the book gives, I think are involved in the problem:

> 2.4. Definition. (Frenet curve)
> Let $c(s)$ be a regular curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$, which is parametrized by arc length and $n$-times continuously differentiable. Then $c$ is called a Frenet curve, if at every point the vectors $c^{\prime}, c^{\prime \prime}, \ldots, c^{(n-1)}$ are linearly independent. The Frenet $n$-frame $e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_n$ is then uniquely determined by the following conditions:
> (i) $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ are orthonormal and positively oriented.
> (ii) For every $k=1, \ldots, n-1$ one has $\operatorname{Lin}\left(e_1, \ldots, e_k\right)=$ $\operatorname{Lin}\left(c^{\prime}, c^{\prime \prime}, \ldots, c^{(k)}\right)$, where $\operatorname{Lin}$ denotes the linear span.
> (iii) $\left\langle c^{(k)}, e_k\right\rangle>0$ for $k=1, \ldots, n-1$.

and

> 2.13. Theorem and definition. (Frenet equations in $\mathbb{R}^n$ )
> Let $c$ be a Frenet curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with Frenet $n$-frame $e_1 \ldots, e_n$. Then there are functions $\kappa_1, \ldots, \kappa_{n-1}$ defined on that curve with $\kappa_1, \ldots, \kappa_{n-2}>0$, so that every $\kappa_i$ is $(n-1-i)$-times continuously differentiable and
> $$
> \left(\begin{array}{c}
> e_1 \\
> e_2 \\
> \vdots \\
> \vdots \\
> \vdots \\
> e_{n-1} \\
> e_n
> \end{array}\right)^{\prime}=\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
> 0 & \kappa_1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
> -\kappa_1 & 0 & \kappa_2 & 0 & \ddots & \vdots \\
> 0 & -\kappa_2 & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
> 0 & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
> \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 & \kappa_{n-1} \\
> 0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & -\kappa_{n-1} & 0
> \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
> e_1 \\
> e_2 \\
> \vdots \\
> \vdots \\
> \vdots \\
> e_{n-1} \\
> e_n
> \end{array}\right) .
> $$
> $\kappa_i$ is called the $i$-th Frenet curvature and the equations are called the Frenet equations.

So my first attempt I thought was an induction over $n$, but it didn't work. So I was thinking in something like QR decomposition, but I'm not sure if it could work. Do you have any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you started by writing out the cases $n=2,3,4$ explicitly? Perhaps this will suggest the proof. Don’t get carried away with fancy matrix nonsense.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas) (paragraph "Formulas in n dimensions") ?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I think I got it.

Comment: You might want to write up an answer yourself :)

Comment: Have a look at this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1950720/305862)